# Only dependency assignment operations are allowed in constructor. No other operations are allowed

Tags: magento2.2, dependency-injection, object-manager, meqp2

MEQP2: How to resolve below issue?

```
abstract class ClassName extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(

        ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,

        ...
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $productHelper->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);
        ...

    }
}
```

Error is :

> Only dependency assignment operations are allowed in constructor. No
>   other operations are allowed. with line
>   `$productHelper->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);`

Note: My class is depend on so many other classes? :(

Answer (score 0):

For resolve this issue you can **create a public or protected property** `$productHelper` and assign `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper` this dependency to this property by `$this->productHelper = $productHelper` and then use this property as a object of the `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product` **class** and perform action like `$this->productHelper->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);`

After doing above please flush your cache and then clear your cache for make it work.
Commands are below:

> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
> ```

Detail code is below:

```
abstract class ClassName extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    public $productHelper;

    public function __construct(

        ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,

        ...
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productHelper = $productHelper;
        $this->productHelper->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);
        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: This way I already Checked. not resolved

Comment: For Coding level your code is ok, but based on MEQP2 sniff  coding standard your code is showing same error. `Only dependency assignment operations are allowed in constructor. No other operations are allowed`